# How to find out what's causing it in an obfuscated java file?

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
    at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(TypeToken.java:84)
    at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(TypeToken.java:62)
    at a.a.b.a.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at a.a.b.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at a.a.b.a.b.deserialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)`
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:682)
    at a.a.b.d.d.b(Unknown Source)
    at a.a.b.i.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

That's the StackTrace to a Java file that I run (Obfuscated), I do not get this when my program isn't obfuscated and ran. So, I am lead to conclude that this is being caused by the obfuscator (ProGuard).

Is there a way I can fix this, or get some information shed on to what may be causing this?

Comment: Edit your question and share your code with us

Comment: How can I provide code when it's obfuscated? Would the non-obfuscated code be required? If so, which parts may I ask?

Comment: But there must be some code that calles to this obfuscated code right ?

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned, when this isn't obfuscated it works fine although when it's obfuscated it throws this error. So I can't really show you the obfuscated code, as it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Not if it's all obfuscated, no.

Comment: @Ben do you have access to the mapping file of the obfuscated code? If so, then look here: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/examples.html

Comment: There is a way to debug the obfuscated code as described by google in here http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html . After you follow the guide, then you could update your question with the content of mapping.txt file.

Comment: Java Reflections and code obfuscation don't play nice together.  I see a reference to `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` in your log. Key word, *Reflective*.  This may be a hint as to what's going on.

Comment: If it is obfuscated, is there not someone who produced this code and supports it?

Comment: Code obfuscation is evil.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.` you're passing some parameter without his type.

Check your function call against google's API over the web to see the differences.

Comment: I see. I've used the mapping technique to get the proper stack trace which points to this code: http://pastebin.com/Mz8evpwf

Comment: Not me, it's a launcher developed by someone else for a game called Minecraft, I'm just adding some extensions that will enhance the game play. Providing the appropriate credits as well

Comment: I am quite curious as to why the line numbers of the errors aren't showing. Is it something to do with running it with the JDK?

Comment: @Ben ProGuard remove debugging information by default. You have to use the `-keepattribute SourceFile,LineNumberTable` option to keep them. See http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/refcard.html

Comment: I've taken a deeper look, and found out whenever Google's fromJson method is being called, I always get the stacktrace: For e.g. 

CompleteVersion version1 = (CompleteVersion)this.gson.fromJson(this.getContent(ex), CompleteVersion.class);

Is getting caught by RuntimeException after obfuscation and when it's executed.

Comment: Is there a way to tell ProGuard to take it easy on the Google GSON when obfuscating? It is changing up values, since I'm passing all the correct params when it comes to the fromJson method in the GSON class. I suspect it may be changing what's being passed.

Comment: I suspect that ProGuard is changing the names of fields being passed into the method fromJson. How exactly would I prevent this from happening in proguardgui?